# Flask request.form not retrieving any data

Tags: python, flask

I'm posting data to the following Flask view using an HTML form. For some reason, the server is never created. I've confirmed that the `create_server` method works from the interpreter. Another form I'm using to log in works. Why isn't this working?

```
@app.route('/add-server/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_server_view():
    if request.method == 'post':
        server_name = request.form['server_name']
        create_server(server_name)
        return redirect(url_for('index')

    return render_template('add_server.html')
```

```html
<form method=post>
    <input name=server_name>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.method` will be in all caps and the comparison is case sensitive.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

[This code in Werkzueg forces the method name to uppercase for consistency.](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/0.12.1/werkzeug/wrappers.py#L640-L643)